# Python Tkinter textarea colorize specific word

Tags: python, tkinter, textarea

how can i colorize a specific word in a textarea? for example when i type "bean" it should be red. but the rest should stay the same

i think this code is everything you guys would need:

```
self.master = master
    self.filename = None

    self.textarea = tk.Text(master, font=font_specs)
    self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(master, command=self.textarea.yview)
    self.textarea.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
    self.textarea.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.textarea.configure(background="#222222", foreground="#fff")
    
    self.menubar = Menubar(self)
    self.statusbar = Statusbar(self)

    self.bind_shortcuts()

    self.textarea.insert
```

Comment: No, i've already tried it @Ronald

Comment: This can be answered by reading the documentation for the Text widget. Read about how to configure and apply tags.